# What doctrine schema handler tools is out there better than mysql-workbench-doctrine-plugin?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, mysql-workbench

I am using mysql-workbench-doctrine-plugin and it is definitely something which is very useful! However I need something more robust which can handle more exceptional cases! The current plug in has some issues like:

1. Generates duplicate relationship name. For example if one table has two separate column having relationship with another particular table, then it will generate same name for the relationship (model class name of that particular table)
2. foreingAlias name: if the table name is user_phonenumber then foreign alias would be userPhonenumber, but it is better to have it like UserPhonenumber as it will look better to call like getUserPhonenumber than getuserPhonenumber. However this can be changed by tweaking the DoctrineExport.grt.lua file of the plugin..
3. if sfGuard plugin is used then all the sfDoctrineGuard related model classes are generated like SfDoctrineGuard* which breaks the plugin as it uses smaller 'sf' not 'Sf' as the name. (this is not a big issue as it is an exception for this plugin) .

What is the situation now is that I need to tweak a lot whenever I make changes to my database design in the workbench and generate yml for doctrine from it. I need something more powerful so that I need less tweaking to work seamlessly back and forth as project grows and evolves! Any suggestion ? Or what do you do when your database is big and changes a lot?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using ORM Designer with great success. Its quirky with Doctrine 2, but it generates the entities for you with proper ORM relationships

http://www.orm-designer.com/

Comment: thanks for your answer! Actually I downloaded and played with the trial version little bit. But coming from workbench, ORM designer's EER diagram looks very novice and sluggish! May be I need to explore it more to realize its value..

Comment: Since that the ORM Designer has had both its visuals and overall speed re-hauled of processing the schema files. It may look little simple and plain but the workflow itself is very good.

Comment: I am a chief developer of the tool and I just want to notice that ORM Designer3 was renamed to Skipper and it's available on [www.skipper18.com](http://www.skipper18.com)